# How Turn off Diacritical marks (accents) in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, editing

On my Mac when I'm using VSCode 1.17.2 whenever I type an opening quote followed by a vowel it removes the quote and makes the vowel into a diacritic (some people might refer to these as accents. An umlaut is an example)

This feature is intensely annoying

How do I turn it off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using a mac mini (macOS) with a dell keyboard plugged in. You have to go into system preferences and set the keyboard up (even though it seems to be working)

After a quick wizard run through I set my keyboard to

`U.S. International -PC`

Seems to behave now

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have an international IME installed.  For support for languages with accented letters, typing `'a` creates `á`, or `"o` creates `ö`.  Make sure you have selected `English(US)` if you don't want this support.  On Windows 10, the IME icon in the taskbar is `ENG` in the image below:

[image: Image of IME menu]

Even if you have an international IME installed, like `ESP` (Spanish), you can type a space after the opening quote to leave an actual single or double quote character: `" o` produces `"o`.

Comment: Its a fair assumption and likely the issue but this only happens to me in VSC on macOS - High Sierra. Which I have set to English (Australian), I've tried US English but no change :(

Comment: @Peter sorry I missed the "on a Mac" part. It does sound like an IME issue, but I'm not familiar with Macs.