# weird dot showing up under letter on pressing ctrl+alt+r on vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, vscode-extensions, rest-client

When i tried using *rest client* inside vs code to send http request via shortcut `ctrl+alt+r` it produced **weird dot** (under the letter which cursor was on while pressing the shortcut)

Once the weird produced it messes up with request body.
Please see the image for reference.

[image: weird dot]

I tried looking up the detail of the shortcut `ctrl+atl+r`. But could not figure out the source of problem.

[image: detail of shortcut ctrl+alt+r]

Answer (score 0):

Those dots are called **diatrics marks**
and found one answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47024685/how-turn-off-diacritical-marks-accents-in-visual-studio-code).
It's something about turning off international keyboards in windows.